# How to modify display of image form metadata after upload on node edit form?

Tags: media

[image]

After uploading an image, how do I hook in and change the display so that Title appears above Alternate text?

Comment: any specific reason for you to display the title tag above and alt tag below

Comment: I am using this to create and sort images for a Galleria slideshow, which uses Title for the Title and Alternate text for the Description.

Comment: You want to change image in that field

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, which I discovered after some further research:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  // If this is an an image on a slideshow
  if (isset($context['form']['type']['#value']) && $context['form']['type']['#value'] == 'slideshow') {
    // Loop through the element children (there will always be at least one).
    foreach (element_children($element) as $key => $child) {
      // Add the new process function to the element
      $element[$key]['#process'][] = '_MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process';
    }
  }
}

function _MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  // Change the way metadata form fields are displayed;
  unset($element['title']['#description']);
  unset($element['alt']['#description']);
  $element['title']['#weight'] = '-4';
  $element['alt']['#title'] = 'Description';
  // Return the altered element
  return $element;
}
```